# How to make Bootstrap cards (using ReactJS) move to new line after three have been rendered?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

On my personal portfolio, I have a "Projects" page where I display different projects using Bootstrap cards. I render them all in from my CardData.js file, then map the values to a ProjectCard component. I would like to have 3 cards per row with the set margins and spacing that I currently have. Currently, if I add more than 3 cards, it smushes the cards all together into one row.

Any help or feedback is appreciated!

- Projects.js (Page component):

```
import '../../App.css'; // main css file //may need to change path
import './projects.css'; // projects css file

import { CardData } from './CardData.js'; // data import for card data

// TODO: Make cards go onto new row when more than three cards are displayed

class Projects extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="project-div">
                <Navbar navId="navb" logoId="logo" logoText="qprice" logoClass="mr-auto" class="navbar bg-white navbar-expand-md sticky-top navbar-fixed-top shadow ml-auto" />
                <h1 id="header-projects" className="font-weight-bold text-uppercase text-center ">Projects</h1>
                <div id="card-div">
                    {CardData.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                            <ProjectCard cardImg={item.cardImg} cardURL={item.cardURL} cardTitle={item.cardTitle} cardText={item.cardText} />
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

- Projects.css:

```
#project-div {
    /*background-image: url("../../img/so-white.png");*/
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url("../../img/topography.png");
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

/* header text */
#header-projects {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    color: #343a40;
}

/* nav links */
.nav a {
    color: black;
}

/* div that holds cards */
#card-div {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}


#portrait {
    width: 300px;
    display: inline;
    border: 5px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.project-cards p {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}

@media (min-width: 1000px)
{
    .project-cards {
        max-width: 40rem;
    }
}
```

- ProjectCards.js (Component for actual cards):

```
class ProjectCards extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="card mx-auto project-cards rounded border shadow">
                <img className="card-img-top" alt="Project cards"src={this.props.cardImg}></img>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <h5 className="card-title font-weight-bold">{this.props.cardTitle}</h5>
                    <p className="card-text">{this.props.cardText}</p>
                    <a href={this.props.cardURL} className="btn">See Project</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

- ProjectCard.css:

```
/* project cards */
.project-cards {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    width: 450px;
    height: 450px;
}

.project-cards h1 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

/* IMPORTANT: images must be a 2:1 width to height ratio. */
.project-cards img {
    height: 50%; 
    width: 100%;
}

.project-cards .btn {
    color: white;
    background-color: #52B788;
}

.project-cards a:hover {
    background-color: #42966f;
}
```

Comment: Bootstrap's [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/card/#grid-cards) should do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like that with Bootstrap Grid System:

```
<Row>
    {CardData.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <Col sm={4}><ProjectCard cardImg={item.cardImg} cardURL={item.cardURL} cardTitle={item.cardTitle} cardText={item.cardText} /></Col>
            )
        })}
    
</Row>
```

Comment: I'm a bit lost on what the sm={4} in the Col tag is. Is this assuming I make a component for columns and then pass a prop in for it's class?

Comment: Col is a styled component from bootstrap. Then passing "sm" as props means the min width of screen that will activate this column number. Max width of a row is 12, so 12/3 = 4, then sm={4} will make 3 columns. More information: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap grid system [Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/) to place objects on a page. for eg, In your case u want to render 3 card on each row, do the following

```
<div className="container">
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col-12  col-lg-4"><ProjectCard/></div>
    <div className="col-12  col-lg-4"><ProjectCard/></div>
    <div className="col-12  col-lg-4"><ProjectCard/></div>
    <div className="col-12  col-lg-4"><ProjectCard/></div>
    <div className="col-12  col-lg-4"><ProjectCard/></div>
    <div className="col-12  col-lg-4"><ProjectCard/></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Above code will place each ProjectCard on 1 row on mobile device using `col-12` and will place 3 ProjectCards on 1 row on desktop using `col-lg-4`.

The grid system will also handle any number of ProjectCards, as the 4th ProjectCard will go on to the next line.

Another point to remember is, when using grid system dont specify width for ProjectCard, as the Grid system will handle the width for you.

Updated code

```
 <div id="card-div" className="row">
  {CardData.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <div className="col-12  col-lg-4">
        <ProjectCard
          cardImg={item.cardImg}
          cardURL={item.cardURL}
          cardTitle={item.cardTitle}
          cardText={item.cardText}
        />
      </div>
    );
  })}
</div>;
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked - only one thing. When I did this, the cards are now not centered on the screen and are aligned to the left. Using the margin property on the .project-cards class only changed the top and bottom margin. How do I align these cards so that they're in the center (horizontally)?